# Convert data.frame into json in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert R data.frame into json file for further calling this json file by jquery within js code.

I have the following data.frame:

```
# Input data.frame
data <- data.frame(Product=c("Prod1","Prod2","Prod3","Prod4"), Val1=c(4,5,2,6.8), Val2=c(6,5,2,7.8), Val3=c(8,5,6,6.7),
               Description=c("Doritos 1.0 Intel PAV UMA","Stag 1.2 Intel PAV UMA","Pike 1.0 Intel Spectre x360",
                             "Antinori 1.2 Intel PAV UMA"))
```

and I need to convert it into json file, the same like this:

```
# Desired Output
[
  ["Product","Val1","Val2","Val3", "Description"],
  ["Prod1",4,6,8,"Doritos 1.0 Intel PAV UMA"],
  ["Prod2",5,5,5,"Stag 1.2 Intel PAV UMA"],
  ["Prod3",2,2,6,"Pike 1.0 Intel Spectre x360"],
  ["Prod4",6.8,7.8,6.7,"Antinori 1.2 Intel PAV UMA"]
]
```

I've tried to use **toJSON** of **jsonlite** package, but the output is not what I need to have as an output.

Could you anyone help me, how could I convert origin data.frame into desired output above. Many thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unname` to get the square brackets in your json output:

```
library(jsonlite)
data <- rbind(names(data), sapply(data, as.character))
toJSON(unname(data), pretty = T)
# [
#   ["Product", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3", "Description"],
#   ["Prod1", "4", "6", "8", "Doritos 1.0 Intel PAV UMA"],
#   ["Prod2", "5", "5", "5", "Stag 1.2 Intel PAV UMA"],
#   ["Prod3", "2", "2", "6", "Pike 1.0 Intel Spectre x360"],
#   ["Prod4", "6.8", "7.8", "6.7", "Antinori 1.2 Intel PAV UMA"]
# ]
```

Alternative:

```
df.toJSON <- function(data) { 
  out <- capture.output(write.csv(data, row.names = FALSE, eol = "],\n"))
  out <- paste(paste0("  [", out, collapse = "\n"))
  out <- substr(out, 0, nchar(out)-1)
  out <- paste0("\n[\n", out, "\n]")
  return(out)
}
cat(df.toJSON(data))
# [
#   ["Product","Val1","Val2","Val3","Description"],
#   ["Prod1",4,6,8,"Doritos 1.0 Intel PAV UMA"],
#   ["Prod2",5,5,5,"Stag 1.2 Intel PAV UMA"],
#   ["Prod3",2,2,6,"Pike 1.0 Intel Spectre x360"],
#   ["Prod4",6.8,7.8,6.7,"Antinori 1.2 Intel PAV UMA"]
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer... but if I try out <- toJSON(unname(data), pretty = T), it resulted into this error message:

Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : x and y must same length.

Comment: Update the `jsonlite` package? Use `jsonlite::toJSON`? The example works fine here. I'm using version 0.9.16.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, it required to update jsonlite package. Oh, maybe one thing i didn't notice:

How could I change your proposed script to have this:

["Product","Val1","Val2","Val3", "Description"],

in first line?

Comment: oops, I didn't notice you want the header in row 1 - see my update.

Comment: Please note that you got strings, now, wrapped in `"`.

Comment: And if I want to have 2-4  variables as a numeric, so what shoud I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76968/discussion-between-martinkabe-and-lukea).

Comment: In that case, you'd probably build the json from scrach - see e.g. the alternative I added.

Comment: And how could I add comma over the each last square bracket in row except of the last one?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need. Great job from your side, thanks a lot.